# hibernate 4 compatibility with spring

Tags: spring, hibernate

Is Hibernate 4.0 compatible with Spring 3.0
I looked into many blogs which says 3.1 and above version of spring is required to use Hibernate 4.0 version. Please clarify the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate 4.x support was available since Spring 3.1 see the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#new-in-3.1-hibernate-4-support).  Given this announcement, I would assume that Hibernate 4.x support was not available in Spring 3.0.